How do I keep the mysql client from echoing commands?
The mysql client on my Macbook echos command lines.  Even when I turn echoing of command lines off in the shell, when I start up the mysql client it immediately begins echoing them.  Then when I exit from the mysql client I find that the echoing of command lines in the shell has been turned back on:
% pwd
pwd
/Users/me
% stty -echo
% pwd
/Users/me
% mysql -u me -pxxx
mysql -u me -pxxx
Welcome etc...
mysql> select 1;
select 1;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit;
% pwd
pwd
/Users/me
%

I would like to turn off command line echoing within the mysql client.  Not a big deal, but I'm debugging my way through a damaged database and it's getting annoying.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html ... see the part where it gives an example with the heading Here is a typical user option file (and of course the part that tells you where to put your option file).

Sorry, I should have mentioned that I've already searched for an option to control command line echoing.  Not finding one I tried stty, which is what I described in my question.
If you or anyone knows of such an option, please let me know.

That doesn't look like a specific mysql issue to me although I don't really know (but according to your output it's echoing pwd which is not a mysql command and even before you start the mysql client - so it just looks like a shell setting). Or in other words, why do you think that has anything to do with mysql?

How are you running the terminal? Are you doing this inside an Emacs shell buffer?

Replying to topsail: But I turn shell echoing off (stty -echo). before starting mysql.  I give a pwd command demonstrating that echoing is actually off.  Then when I exit from mysql, echoing in the shell has been turned back on again.  To Barmar: Yes, this is inside an Emacs shell.  How did you guess?  Let me try the same thing in a Mac terminal...Interesting.  The problem is not present in a Mac terminal, only an Emacs shell.  Do you know what is happening?

Barmar provided the necessary hint.  I was running inside an Emacs shell.  Set this Emacs variable to true so that comint echos input to the output:
(setq comint-process-echoes t)

Once this is set, the setting for "stty echo" no longer matters

If you where under a normal (not emacs) session you could have type set +v to turn echoing off (and set -v) to turn it on)
